# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una única barra en un gráfico de barras plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

Tengo un gráfico con la siguiente estructura:

```
Especie <- c("Perros","Gatos","Pájaros","Total")
Cantidad <- c(3,2,4,9)

df <- data.frame(Especie,Cantidad)

grafico <- plot_ly(df,
        x = ~Especie,
        y = ~Cantidad,
        type = "bar")
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible indicar que se pinte la barra correspondiente al "Total" de otro color, basado en su valor en la columna 'Especie' (no su ubicación)?
Y alternativamente, ¿Es posible indicar que se pinte de otro color a la barra correspondiente al mayor valor de 'Cantidad'?

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que hacer dos cosas (1) mapear la dimensión de color: `color = ~Especie` y (2) pasar un vector con los colores para cada categoría o barra: `colors = c('#393975', '#393975', '#393975', '#782424')`

```
plot_ly(df,
       x = ~Especie,
       y = ~Cantidad,
       color = ~Especie,
       colors = c('#393975', '#393975', '#393975', '#782424'),
       type = "bar")
```

En este caso usamos una notación RGB en hexadecimal, cualquier "color picker" (hay montones online) te permitirá seleccionar el color adecuado, en este caso queremos que las tres primeras categorías tengan un color y la del total otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]